# Control keys not working - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday on my machine, where I also have installed a windows 10. Yesterday, ctrl,shift, alt and other control keys worked perfectly, but now they suddenly stopped working. What could be the problem. On windows, they work perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you perform any update?

Comment: I tried restarting, but nothing. After that I changed boot order and it worked. Maybe this was nőt the problem, but it worked.

Comment: Same with me... and annoying !

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the error...

[image: Ubuntu locate pointer checkbox]

Just disable the `Locate Pointer` option and re-enjoy the Ctrl key again !

FYI: [press here.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/ctrl-key-not-being-recognised-4175584236/)